# Can Microsoft resolve an IPv6 for Exchange Online?

Tags: ipv6, exchangeonline

Is there a way to resolve an IPv6 address for Exchange Online like : mydomain.mail.protection.outlook.com?

I only got an IPv4 address for the mailserver at mydomain.mail.protection.outlook.com

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes they can, but you need to contact support to have it enabled. which is in the link in one of the answers below. (that is the owner of the domain have to ask for it to be enabled) https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/mailprotectionoutlookcom-missing-aaaa-ipv6/b32eb8ca-de1f-41cd-880b-65b77b6e90b2

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this blog: [Add support for anonymous inbound email over IPv6 in Microsoft 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/support-for-anonymous-inbound-email-messages-over-ipv6?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: No, i mean: Can Microsoft please resolve IPv6 on EOL.